# What internet filtering system can selectively block a proxy-accessed website?

Tags: wireless-networking, proxy, lan

In my public library there is free wifi. Some websites are blocked by a content blocking system. I used a free proxy to access these sites. Now, after using this method for a few days, some of the sites become blocked again (but not all). This includes https websites.

I can connect to my proxy no problem, but how come the content filterting system can block certain sites now? especially the https, which should be encrypted...

Comment: You need to be more specific on what type of proxy you are using.

Comment: @Ramhound I didn't know that. So the security is limited if the proxy provider does not offer https or socks5. I am using https, at least the free website said it was...

Comment: @jiggunjer - Answer Moab's question.

Comment: It is because the secure connection is between you and the free access which makes a secure connection with the server.  In other words your traffic isn't encrypted directly to the site, its encrypted to the access point, then encrypted to the server.  As for the reason its now blocked again,its normal, to adjust filtering rules your traffic to the sites were logged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely thing that is happening is that they are using a deep packet inspection capable security appliance.

What is happening is that the appliance has intercepted your HTTPS handshake with the server and **it** has taken on the handshake with the server so that it creates the secure link. It has, in the mean time, pretended to be the secure server to you and presented a different certificate. This is often called a "man-in-the-middle attack" though in this case, it isn't really an attack.

It means that the security appliance can continue to inspect the traffic as it decrypts what comes from you to it, inspects it, then re-encrypts to the destination. Obviously this is not good if you are trying to do something that really should be secure (e.g. Internet banking or talking to Wikileaks!).

The reason the sites appear available and then not is because the appliance does dynamic scoring of connections. When it comes across one it doesn't recognise - such as you connecting to a site via VPN, it will try to assign a risk level to it and possibly do other "clever" processing. Eventually it works out that it doesn't want to let you through.

Comment: If it is a true VPN connection, the appliance cannot see anything inside the encrypted VPN tunnel.

Comment: That is correct @Moab, but I don't believe it is a true VPN. The OP talks about a "proxy" so this will be a simple HTTPS web proxy service designed to try and bypass local restrictions. These are susceptible to MITM attacks just like an ordinary website.

Comment: Would a socks5 proxy be less susceptible? @Julian Knight

Comment: @jiggunjer - It all depends on the network setup.  If all secure connections are being handled by the network, then any secure connection, wouldn't actually be secure.  It would be secure from anyone on the outside, but anyone within the network could have access, it really wouldn't be secure

Comment: What you really need is a proper VPN that starts on you PC and goes through to a secure server at the other end. Because such a VPN does not rely on a 1-way SSL/TLS trust but a 2-way trust from within your PC, it would not be susceptible to a MITM attack. Oh and you need to do the first login from a trusted location to be absolutely sure you have the correct server fingerprint. If you ever get a warning about a changed certificate or fingerprint, read it carefully and work out whether it is legitimate, many times it won't be.

Comment: So a common free proxy (like the http or socks5 lists on the web) can't handle any additional encryption like ssh?

Comment: Some http proxies can handle SSL/TLS encryption, however, you are back to the same problem. Similarly, Socks does not provide any encryption itself. As stated, you need a device level VPN.